# Casting numbers separated by commas to a string not returning results in JavaScript function but entering the values manually works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have a JavaScript function that is used to retrieve tag ID numbers (separated by commas) from an asp.net label. (FYI, this is being used with the jQuery select2 multi select drop down). When I attempt to read the string of numbers separated by commas from the code, I do not get any results. There is no error in the browser console. However, if I manually insert the data it works just fine - even thought the data appears to be exactly the same in both cases. Here is an example:

This works great:

```
function GetTags() {           
$(".js-class").val([1,2]); //manually entering the numbers here.
$(".js-class").trigger('change');
}
```

When I attempt to pull the numbers from a label, it doesn't work even though the string is exactly the same: 1,2

```
function GetTags() {      
var data = document.getElementById('MainContent_lblTagIDS').innerText; //1,2 is being returned from this label
$(".js-class").val([data]);
$(".js-class").trigger('change');
}
```

Here is how I'm parsing the data within my code behind method:

```
 var SelectedValues = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<int>("TAGIDS")).ToArray();
 lblTagsIDS.Text = string.Join(",", SelectedValues);
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "myFunction", "GetTags();", true);
```

Comment: did you try using double quotes like this  "\'"  ?

Comment: @tiborK Yes, I tried that and it didn't work. I've also tried "'".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found. I needed to keep each number in different arrays of sequence by calling split. I then used the jQuery each() function to loop through each element of the target jQuery object.

```
function GetTags() {
    var data = document.getElementById('MainContent_lblTagsIDS').innerText;    
    var newarray = data.split(",");
    $.each($(".js-class"), function () {
        $(this).val(newarray);
    });
    $(".js-class").trigger('change'); // Notify any JS components that the value changed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is plain JS

HTML

```
<input id="t" onchange="changeHandler()" type="text" value="" />
<p id="p"></p>
```

JS

```
function changeHandler() {
    var text = document.querySelector('#t').value;
    document.querySelector("#p").innerHTML = "\'"+text+ "\'";
}
```

Comment: I now believe the problem may not have anything to do with the quotes at all, but how the data is formatted. I removed single quotes completely from the manual test and it still works, even with numbers separated by commas ex: 1, 2  so I may have been prematurely focused on the wrong piece. Still, I don't understand why it should matter. A number separated by a comma is still a string. Correct? I'll update my original post to reflect these observations. Thanks

Comment: @Shane that is correct. One question: when you say manual typing, you have multiple input fields with "js-class" class?

Comment: No, I mean manually entering the numbers in my JavaScript function. I'm not actually placing them in an input field.